# title mis missing in acl.xml in COZYVISION_Smsalert extension

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.8

here is my acl.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::admin" >
                <resource id="COZYVISION_Smsalert::sms" title="SMS Alert" sortOrder="100">
                    <resource id="COZYVISION_Smsalert::config" title="Config" sortOrder="10" />
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::config">
                            <resource id="COZYVISION_Smsalert::sms_config" title="Configuration" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: solved by myself

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::admin" title="admin" >
                <resource id="COZYVISION_Smsalert::sms" title="SMS Alert" sortOrder="100">
                    <resource id="COZYVISION_Smsalert::config" title="Config" sortOrder="10" />
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::stores" title="stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::stores_settings" title="stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::config" title="config">
                            <resource id="COZYVISION_Smsalert::sms_config" title="Configuration" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```